# How translate from curl terminal to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl, terminal

I need to send data to a card processing company, but the company api code example uses curl terminal.

this is the code format that the api accepts

```
curl -X POST -u "login:password" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-PJ-Application-Key: YOUR_PRODUCTION_APP_KEY" \
-d "action=CHARGE" \
-d "cardTrack=%B4444333322221111^First/Last^1712980100000?;4444333322221111=1712980100000?" \
-d "amountBase=1.00" \
"https://api.payjunction.com/transactions"
```

Now I want to know what does that mean in javascript terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.payjunction.com/transactions",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        action: "CHARGE",
        cardTrack: "%B4444333322221111^First/Last^1712980100000?;4444333322221111=1712980100000?",
        amountBase: 1.00
    },
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-PJ-Application-Key": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_APP_KEY"
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```